# Summarize the same key name in php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, summarize

I have an array like this:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [id_station] => 2397
                [hour] => 12
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [cameraon] => 355654
                        [cameraoff] => 4532
                        [camerabroken] => 76745
                        ...
                    )
            )
[1] => Array
            (
                [id_station] => 2399
                [hour] => 13
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [cameraon] => 3905466
                        [cameraoff] => 1672
                        [camerabroken] => 70780
                        ...
                    )
            )
```

I want to add one more row = total of all items

```
[1] => Array
            (
                [id_station] => 
                [hour] => 
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [cameraon] => 4261120
                        [cameraoff] => 6204
                        [camerabroken] => 147525
                    )
            )
```

I used `array_sum(array_column($array["data], 'cameraon'))` but I have to do for all items `cameraon`, `cameraoff`, `camerabroken` (I have a hundred items).

Is there any way to get total row in this case?

Comment: post with expected output array

Comment: hi kunal, the expected array is the array with summarize of all child items of data element, total cameraon, cameraoff, camerabroken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I assume that you don't know the depth of `data` sub-array. (that is how many key-value pairs are there)***

So do like below:-

```
$final_array = [];
$final_array['id_station'] ='';
$final_array['hour'] ='';
foreach($original_array as $original_arr){
  foreach($original_arr['data'] as $key=>$original){
     $final_array['data'][$key] +=$original;
  }
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/926729

Comment: cool, but can we use function with 1 foreach instead of 2 foreach?

Comment: I am afraid you can not

Comment: @sontd  still facing issue? One thing-> if you know that fix number of keys inside `data` array can come then only you can shorten the code using `array_column()`

Comment: unfortunately the number of keys inside data array was not fixed. anyway I can use for temporary solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You wish to sum the columnar data, so leveraging `array_sum()` and `array_column()` are wise choices.  The only thing left to do is set up the loop.

You can first isolate the `data` subarrays using `array_column()` then "drill down" into the first subarray to iterate each column.  Use the column names to access all values in all columns.  This makes the method dynamically successful regardless of the complexity of your `data` subarrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/O6Q7p))

```
$array=[
    [
        'id_station'=>2397,
        'hour'=>12,
        'data'=>['cameraon'=>355654,'cameraoff'=>4532,'camerabroken'=>76745]
    ],
    [
        'id_station'=>2399,
        'hour'=>14,
        'data'=>['cameraon'=>3905466,'cameraoff'=>1672,'camerabroken'=>70780]
    ]
];
$datas=array_column($array,'data');  // isolate the data subarrays
foreach(current($datas) as $column=>$data){  // iterate the columns
    $result[$column]=array_sum(array_column($datas,$column));  // sum the column values
}
$array[]=['id_station'=>'','hour'=>'','data'=>$result];  // completenew item and append
var_export($array);  // print to screen
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id_station' => 2397,
    'hour' => 12,
    'data' => 
    array (
      'cameraon' => 355654,
      'cameraoff' => 4532,
      'camerabroken' => 76745,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id_station' => 2399,
    'hour' => 14,
    'data' => 
    array (
      'cameraon' => 3905466,
      'cameraoff' => 1672,
      'camerabroken' => 70780,
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id_station' => '',
    'hour' => '',
    'data' => 
    array (
      'cameraon' => 4261120,
      'cameraoff' => 6204,
      'camerabroken' => 147525,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: @sontd your currently accepted answer is not professional grade because it will generate Notices due to using `+=` on undeclared array elements.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/MlUgb  It is also incorrect, that you MUST use two loops.  My method shows how using `array_column()` is a sensible and effective alternative.  My method will run just as fast without producing Notices.